# Date Picker Blue

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm successfully setting a date-picker with an initial date from a plist, but I see some unwanted blue values in the month, day, and year components, presumably corresponding to current date.  So if today is April 18, 2010 and initial date being set is March 19, 2008, it looks like this (bold represents the blue):

```
     January  17 2006
    February  18 2007
    ------------------------------
       March  19 2008 
    ------------------------------
       April  20 2009
         May  21 2010
```

First question is: How do I get rid of the blue?

And second question: Ideally, how do I get it to look like this?

```
     January  17 2006
    February  18 2007
    ------------------------------
      March  19 2008 
    ------------------------------
       April  20 2009
         May  21 2010
```

Third question, totally unrelated and not as important:  How could I have gotten the above to show in blue rather than bold?  I see blue in code snippets all the time.

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I do not believe it's possible to suppress the coloring of the current date components in blue.  You could always [file a feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com/) for this functionality.

As a last resort, you could implement your own (or Google for "generic date picker" - someone has already done this).

I think the code sample formatter automagically makes things blue that it thinks are keywords, like:

```
UIDatePicker* myPicker;
```

I didn't tell it to make that blue, it just is.